# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError occurs when submodule access the static method in interface of dependences

Tags: java, android

I'm doing something like this:

- Create a new Java Library, add an interface, which contains a static method, and package it as a jar.

```java
public interface InterfaceTest {
    static int test() {
        return 0x16;
    }
}
```

- Create a new Android Library and name it `sdk`, refer to the jar in step 1: `api files('libs/lib.jar')`.

```
public class Main {
    public static int create() {
        return InterfaceTest.test();
    }
}
```

- Create a new Android Application and directly reference the module in step 2: `implementation project(':sdk')`.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Toast.makeText(this, Main.create().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

- Use `assembleDebug` to package step 3, get `app-debug.apk`, install and start, the application crashes, and the error log is as follows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: io.github.sgpublic.jartest, PID: 18931
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method test()I in class Lio/github/sgpublic/lib/InterfaceTest; or its super classes (declaration of 'io.github.sgpublic.lib.InterfaceTest' appears in /data/app/~~YvfX66D6YZcRxdFMHi5zSg==/io.github.sgpublic.jartest-FIbOhcbOzGnvL9VwL_K9UA==/base.apk)
    at io.github.sgpublic.sdk.Main.create(Main.java:12)
    at io.github.sgpublic.jartest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:12)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8143)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8114)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3513)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3700)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8060)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

I simplified the code to get this sample project: [sgpublic/JarTestApplication](https://github.com/sgpublic/JarTestApplication)，and I also post this question on [Google Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/265195801)

I'm wondering if there is a temporary solution that will allow me to circumvent this problem temporarily, thank you!

Comment: *NoSuchMethodError* if you use incompatible libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140508065?pli=1

Solution: add this line to `gradle.properties`

```
android.enableDexingArtifactTransform.desugaring=false
```